# Is it possible to use Three.js to determine the wall thickness of an STL file?

Tags: print-quality, stl

I am using a node app that displays stls online & analyzes them. Is it possible to determine the minimum wall thickness of the stl just like 3D Hubs print analyzer does?

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Comment: Absolute Thickness? Relative thickness? In extrusions?

Comment: Do you mean you're *writing* the node app? If you're just *using* the app, it doesn't matter if three.js can do it, it only matters whether the app can do it.

Answer (score 5):

An STL file is a surface model file. From Wikipedia you can [read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/STL_(file_format)) that:

> STL files describe only the surface geometry of a three-dimensional
>   object without any representation of color, texture or other common
>   CAD model attributes.

This implies that there is no such thing as a wall thickness, as such you will not be able to determine the wall thickness (it is infinitesimally small). You might be interested in part thickness at a certain position; part thickness and wall thickness for 3D printing are determined when the STL model is sliced into sliced for creating 3D printer code.

Comment: yes and no: STL could contain a relative wall thickness... if the wall has inside and outside wall modeled....

Comment: One thing is wall thickness as part of the model (model wall) and other the wall thickness as the (shield) to be printed, this part is according how many lines you need on your print that coul be from 1 line to 5 or more is your models supports those number of lines; if not the slicer just will apply that number of lines that fits inside de model walls, for example just one line. If the CAD has a measing rule and the STL is showing (of course) the walls these can be measured; obviuosly the shield cant be measured due is part of the printing process.

Comment: @FernandoBaltazar STL does not contain any information about the number of shells or infill. it is just the outer shells. if shells are nested into each other, they can generate internal walls.

Comment: @Trish Right, I'm not telling nothing about STL information; I'm talking about Object and its dimension because is a figure so has dimensions and that can be resized. Also I pointed as obvious the shields can't be measured due that parameters are part of printing process, this mean that are variants depending on each user and each machine.